# Error while creating spatial database connection

Tags: arcgis-10.0, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, spatial-database, connection

I'm using ArcGIS 10.0, and I've already created my database using "ArcSDE for PostgreSQL Post installation" ..

My database is successfully created in PostgreSQL and now that I'm trying to create a spatial database connection from ArcMap, so I went to :

ArcCatalog ==> Database connections ==> Add spatial Database connection..

I've filled all the textboxes with the needed information and when I test the connexion before I submit, I get this error :

> Failed to connect to the specified server.
>
> Entry for SDE instance not found in services file.

Although I think I've provided the right information as below :

> Server : localhost
>
> Service : sde:postgres:localhost
>
> Database : my_project

Comment: are you trying to connect on the *same* computer that postgres is installed on?

Answer (score 1):

It's talking about the *services* file `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\services`:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-1999 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This file contains port numbers for well-known services defined by IANA
#
# Format:
#
# <service name>  <port number>/<protocol>  [aliases...]   [#<comment>]
#

echo                7/tcp
echo                7/udp
discard             9/tcp    sink null
discard             9/udp    sink null
systat             11/tcp    users                  #Active users
systat             11/tcp    users                  #Active users
daytime            13/tcp
daytime            13/udp
qotd               17/tcp    quote                  #Quote of the day
qotd               17/udp    quote                  #Quote of the day
```

add the line `ESRI_SDE <PORT>/TCP ESRI_SDE_CONNECTION` at the end of the file - substitute your port number of course. I had issues editing this on win 7 as it's a protected system file, it wouldn't let me overwrite, I had to save as text, rename the `services` to `services.old` and then `services.txt` to `services`. Note `services` has no extension.

This entry should be on *both* sides, so check that it's in your server as well. This instructs windows as to what ports to listen to, which could be for security reasons but either way if it's not in the list windows wont communicate over it.

ESRI reccomends the [direct connection to SDE](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Setting_up_a_direct_connection_to_PostgreSQL/002p0000003q000000/) rather than the services connection, however the client files are not installed by default, you may recieve an error message: `ERROR .. Cursor_Tuple_Fraction..`. If this occurs you need to get these from your ESRI global account \ software download \ DBMS client files and follow the install directions

Here is the contents of the batch files. Assuming DBname is set to the name of the database, host is set to the computername and Port is set to the port you want to use. Passwords and paths are masked, use your own. The batch file should be run from the sdehome\bin directory or the system may not find the programs to run.

Set your parameters by using `set param=` like this:

```
set DBname=sde
set host=fred
set port=9999
```

Don't use those parameters, they're fake. You need to put your own parameters in. Note also there is no spaces between the parameter and its value.

```
SDEsetup -o install -d POSTGRESQL -u sde -p ############# -D %DBname% -l c:\path\to\license.file
:: now ready for direct connection

:: write to the SDE services and System Services the port numbers
echo sde_%DBname% %Port%/tcp #ArcSDE for PostgreSQL on %DBname% >> %sdehome%etc\services.sde
echo sde_%DBname% %Port%/tcp #ArcSDE for PostgreSQL on %DBname% >> SystemServices=%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\services

:: create the DBinit for this service
:: double arrows append to the file
echo set PGHOST = %host% > %sdehome%etc\dbinit_sde_%DBname%.sde
echo set PGPORT = %Port% >> %sdehome%etc\dbinit_sde_%DBname%.sde
echo set SDE_DATABASE = %DBname% >> %sdehome%etc\dbinit_sde_%DBname%.sde

:: register the service
sdeservice -o create -d POSTGRESQL -p ############# -i sde_%DBname% -s %host%
:: Set the ADMIN_DATABASE for this service
sdeservice -o modify -r ADMIN_DATABASE -v %DBname% -d postgresql -i sde_%DBname% -p #############
```

As you can see there's a lot more to creating a service. It needs to be registered in the SDE services, system services and a dbinit file created. If you put this into a batch file you can change the parameters. Note: 5151 is the default SDE port, each new database MUST have a new port number. I googled for a port list and found some free space in the high numbers but later abandoned the use of services in favor of the less complicated direct connection.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @Michael Miles-Stimson I will try that and see if it solves the problem

Comment: Please refer my previous question, are you trying to connect on the *same* computer postgresql is installed on?

Comment: I just edited the services file and I actually found this line : esri_sde 5151/tcp #ArcSDE for PostgreSQL  but when I checked in PostgreSQL I found that my port was 5432, so I changed that.. I've retested the database connection and yet I still have the same error :(

Comment: Yes I'm tryin to connect on the same computer

Comment: SDE is different to PostgreSQL. The port 5432 is for PGadmin and others to talk directly to the database... SDE sits on top of this and serves on 5151. this is how it should be Postgres on 5432 and SDE on 5151. Consider using the direct connection SDE:Postgresql:computername, it is reccomended by ESRI

Comment: Have you edited the pg_hba.conf to allow connections? Localhost may not be recognized, use the computername or 127.0.0.1 instead.

Comment: So what should I do? I've edited now the port on PostgreSQL. It's now localhost:5151 instead of localhost:5432.. But I get this message when I try to connect to the server : Server doesn't listen...

Comment: No I haven't edited the pg_hba.conf file, could u tell me what am I  supposed to edit please?

Comment: Server doesn't listen is a pg_hba.conf problem. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html something like host    all             all             127.0.0.1       255.255.255.255     trust if you're not worried about security issues. Put the ports back to the way they were.

Comment: Yes, make postgres 5432 and SDE 5151. Also, it would be a good idea to put PostgreSQL 5432/TCP in the services file if it's not already there. That would be required for a direct connection. Reboot is not needed for edits to the services. After editing the pg_hba.conf restart postgres either using PGAdmin or by stopping and starting the service.

Comment: For the pg_hba.conf file, I found this : 

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5

I think it's all good isn't it ? the md5 is just for encrypting the password, security stuff right?

Comment: By the way, when I went to Services, I found ArcSDE service(esri_sde) not on, so I tried switching its status to : Start, but it gave me an error by the end saying : Le service ArcSDE Service (esri_sde) sur Ordinateur local a démarré et s'est ensuite arrêté. Certains services s'arrêtent automatiquement s'ils ne sont pas utilisés par d'autres services ou programmes. I'm lost honestly.. There seem to be an error within each move I make :/

Comment: I agree that you're lost.  At this point you should uninstall all the software and start over again.  Next time, do not change any port numbers from their defaults, and do not bother trying to install an ArcSDE service.  All you were missing was a proper pg_hba.conf entry, which will probably involve whatever network you are on besides loopback (127.0.0.1).  At this point, talking to Tech Support is strongly advised.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Vince and @MichaelMiles-Stimson.. I will do that and try to re-install the whole software and see if that'll solve the problem.

Comment: So I have reinstalled the whole software, the arcsde service is now on, and now when I launch the post installation I have this error at at repository setup step : The ArcSDE repository was unsuccessfully completed. Would you like to view this error? And when I click Yes, a wise_err.log file pop up containing the following lines :

Comment: OPEN: No such file or directory
ERROR: Couldn't open C:\Program\etc\giomgr.defs file.
ERROR: Reading "DATA_DICTIONARY" keyword info. SES_dbtuneFile_read_sysconfig() (ret = -287)
OPEN: No such file or directory
C:\Program: No such file or directory
ERROR: Couldn't open C:\Program\etc\giomgr.defs file.
Error: Operation Failed (-1).
       SDE release install not completed. 
Check SDEHOME\etc\sde_setup.log for more details.

Any idea on what the problem is now ?

Comment: Check the system environment variable sde_home, it is searching for files and cannot find them where they are expected, it should be the path to your SDE install. It is best if you install SDE to c:\SDE or c:\ESRI_SDE or something like that there may be a problem with spaces in the path name.

Comment: Here's my system environment variable in Path : c:\Program Files\ArcGIS\ArcSDE\pgexe\bin
Should I just move the ArcSDE directory to C:\ ??

Comment: No don't move anything, that would mess with registry set locations and you may not be able to uninstall and have to reformat your computer. The environment variable is called **sde_home**. If it's having issues in program files then uninstall and reinstall to a location that doesn't have spaces in the path name.

Comment: Here's what the sde_setup.log file contains : 
[Mon Jun 16 22:40:35 2014] ev.SQLstate = 42P01
SDE DBMS Error: -37  ERROR:  relation "sde.sde_layers" does not exist
[Mon Jun 16 22:40:35 2014] ev.SQLstate = 42P01
SDE DBMS Error: -37  ERROR:  relation "sde.sde_server_config" does not exist
[Mon Jun 16 22:40:35 2014] ev.SQLstate = 42P01
SDE DBMS Error: -37  ERROR:  relation "sde.sde_dbtune" does not exist

Comment: [Mon Jun 16 22:40:35 2014] ERROR: (-287) Unable to read system table storage config from C:\Program\etc\dbtune.sde
[Mon Jun 16 22:40:35 2014] Warning: Unable to read system storage parameters from dbtune (-287)
[Mon Jun 16 22:40:35 2014] ev.SQLstate = 42P01
SDE DBMS Error: -37  ERROR:  relation "sde.sde_server_config" does not exist
[Mon Jun 16 22:40:35 2014] ERROR, SDEHOME: Cannot access C:\Program
[Mon Jun 16 22:40:35 2014] ST_GEOMETRY install not completed (-1).
[Mon Jun 16 22:40:35 2014] ERROR installing/upgrading ArcSDE, Error = -1

Comment: Is your SDE database named anything but sde? It looks like the kind of error you would get if you haven't changed your admin_database (see your other post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102053/cant-start-arcsde-esri-sde-service/102067#102067)

Comment: No my sde database is already created and it's named sde

Comment: It was created previously!

Comment: Try removing and redoing the post-install or SDEsetup.exe on the existing database... something hasn't stuck. But first you are definitely having an issue with *c:\Program* from the log.

Comment: Okay I'll do that.

Comment: Stupid question : Concerning the creation of another database with the sde schema, should I just go the postgres and then create it from there ? or should I be going throught this ArcSDE post instal?

Comment: I've tried creating a database on postgresql with the sde tablespace but after it's created I only get public in the schema, I don't see sde

Comment: The post install expects to create the database. I personally use the command line SDEsetup and create the database using PGadmin with the template_postgis as a template, as I mentioned previously we use PG_Geometry for compatibility with other systems and direct connect. If you like I can put the instruction in my post. **oops, it's sdehome not sde_home** sorry!

Comment: Yes please, u can put the instruction, that'll be very thoughtful of you Sir!
Well like I mentionned below I have removed PostGIS during the re-install process, so could that be related to the problem ?

Comment: SDEsetup in the bin folder of ArcSDE? When I click on it the command line comes and goes in a blink of an eye :/

Comment: It's a command line tool, if you double click it will show a usage statement and then exit immediately. This happens in a flash. If you want to see the usage statement then open a command prompt and type *cd %sdehome%bin* then type *SDEsetup*. The link to the usage is on your other post.

Comment: sdesetup -o update_key -d POSTGRESQL -u admin_user -p password -D DBname -l license_file

Concerning the licence, what exactly am I suppose tu put there ? Shall I go to the ecp file and open it with notepad and then paste what line exactly ?

Comment: No, just give the full path to the ecp file.

Comment: When mentionning the sde databse I have this message : Successfully updated authorizarion key
But how to create another database now with an sde schema ?

Comment: If you are using st_geometry just create a blank database using PGAdmin (or similar) and run the batch file on it. Remember to change values for DBname and Port. If you are using pg_geometry create the database with the template_postgis as a template and then run the batch file on it.

Comment: I've already replaced the st_geometry in the lib folder of Postgres (I'm using st_geometry).. I don't understand this part though "run the batch file on it" ?

Comment: copy the code from my post and save it as type *.bat*, edit it in notepad and save as often as necessary then drag 'n drop into a command window, press enter and the system will run the instructions. That is how to run a batch file. Alternately you can just double click on the file and it will run.

Comment: While creating the DB at PG Admin, in the tablespace I put pg_default right? And the template I leave it blank (knowing that I don't have postgis installed, since I removed it)?

Comment: Yes, pg_default tablespace and no template. Don't assign permissions at this stage.

Comment: I get this error : Error: Underlying DBMS error (-51).
       Error upgrading authorization key.

Comment: -51 is a not-my-responsibility error: An error was returned from the database that was not recognized by ArcSDE or the client application. Check the DBMS logs for more information. Read the PostgreSQL log and see what's there.

Comment: The sdedc_PostgreSQL.log file has soo many lines in it, here's what's at the bottom as it's referring I guess to this time's manipulation : CAN'T OPEN INSTANCE: sde:postgresql.
Spatial Engine Connection Failed (-162).
Cannot Get Access to Instance sde:postgresql
ev.SQLstate = 3F000
SDE DBMS Error: -51  ERROR:  schema "sde" does not exist

ev.SQLstate = 3F000
SDE DBMS Error: -51  ERROR:  schema "sde" does not exist

CAN'T OPEN INSTANCE: sde:postgresql.
Spatial Engine Connection Failed (-51).
Cannot Get Access to Instance sde:postgresql

Comment: It says there's no sde schema , well obviously since the database was created initially without any schema, and I'm expecting to get the sde schema using that code in command line, but no result :(

Comment: Just in case this problem persists and I can't create a database with sde schema, can I start working on my project within the "sde" database? Because I have to start working and this problem is blocking me so far :( I will still try to solve this problem of course but I really have to start working
By the way when I go to ArcCatalog and try to make a connection with sde database I get : connexion succeded!But I can't proceed with the post install while creating another database, now I've tried creating another databse and I block at the repository setup phase with the same error that pops up:

Comment: In the wise_err.log file : 
OPEN: No such file or directory
ERROR: Couldn't open C:\Program\etc\giomgr.defs file.
ERROR: Reading "DATA_DICTIONARY" keyword info. SES_dbtuneFile_read_sysconfig() (ret = -287)
OPEN: No such file or directory
C:\Program: No such file or directory
ERROR: Couldn't open C:\Program\etc\giomgr.defs file.
Error: Operation Failed (-1).
       SDE release install not completed. 
Check SDEHOME\etc\sde_setup.log for more details.

Comment: I've tried creating a feature class within the sde database, but I get this error at the end : Failed to create feature class. Database user name and current user schema do not match.
Knowing that postgres is the user !

Comment: No, sde is the user. The postgres (postgresql super user) and the SDE super user are two separate entities, it just happens that you know both passwords. In an enterprise environment you would perhaps know the sde user password but definitely not the postgres password. You are still having problems with the space in the install path that need to be rectified.

Comment: Every user that connects to SDE **must** have have a schema in the database. If you want multiple users you must create a schema for each. Only the sde schema is created by default so connecting using postgres is causing problems because it doesn't have a matching schema in the database. It is recommended that you create the database with *sde* as the user but then connect later as yourself to edit/view the data, to do that you would have to create a user for yourself in PostgreSQL, added a schema and given yourself permissions in the data (using ArcCatalog, connecting as sde)

Comment: Well, I've redone the whole installation.. now my ArcGIS folder and all are on this path : C:\ArcGIS
I proceed with installation, didn't change any port, everything goes well, concerning ArcSDE's installation, I get to the "ArcSDE service information", and at this phase I get this error : An error was encountered while running ArcSDE Post Installation. Could not start ArcSDE -- Check Network, $SDEHOME disk, DBMS settings and dbinit.sde.

Comment: And by the way, I've noticed something. When I check the environment variable, I have this : C:\ArcGIS\ArcSDE\pgexe\bin 
But when I go to the commande line and I check using SET, I find that my SDEHOME =C:\ArcGIS\ArcSDE\pgexe\
No bin folder on the path? Why ?

Comment: That's unusual, it's not something I could answer unless I was there. Is it working yet?

Comment: Problem solved, I've managed to create a database connection between Arccatalog and PostgreSQL.. It was a licence problem. I've proceeded with the post install to create a database with an sde schema but before that I had to uncheck the creation of arcsde service, otherwise the install won't complete. So for now, the arcsde service isn't running.

Comment: That's great. I've had no problem with the direct connection; I could see no difference between direct connect and service connect with respect to speed.

Answer (score 1):

Your Direct Connect database reference is incorrect -- ArcSDE expects "sde:**postgresql**:hostname" for PostgreSQL, so it's falling back to a network services entry, and not finding that either.

The syntax is much easier at 10.1 and 10.2, since the "sde:*rdbmskey*:*options*" instance is replaced with a dynamic form.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Vince.. I've corrected it but I still have the same error, what could be wrong ?